# Turn values in a column in a dataframe into their own indicator columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

If I have a column (variable) in a data frame with say 3 values, I want to create a new column for each of these values that is 1 if the value is true and 0 if the value isn't. For example,

```
one=data.frame(id=c(1:6), status=c("good", "bad", "ok", "ok", "good", "bad"))
# should turn into
#id good bad ok 
#1   1   0   0
#2   0   1   0
#3   0   0   1
#4   0   0   1
#5   1   0   0
#6   0   1   0
```

Is it possible to do for multiple columns with a single line of code? I have 64 columns.

```
multiple=data.frame(id=c(1:6), 
     status=c("good", "bad", "ok", "ok", "good", "bad"), 
     breakfast=c("eggs", "sausage", "eggs", "sausage", "sausage", "eggs"))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table`

```
out <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(one))
```

-output

```
out
#  bad good ok
#1   0    1  0
#2   1    0  0
#3   0    0  1
#4   0    0  1
#5   0    1  0
#6   1    0  0
```

---

For the second case

```
out_lst <- lapply(names(multiple)[-1], function(x) 
              as.data.frame.matrix(table(multiple[c('id', x)])))
```

-output

```
out_lst
[[1]]
  bad good ok
1   0    1  0
2   1    0  0
3   0    0  1
4   0    0  1
5   0    1  0
6   1    0  0

[[2]]
  eggs sausage
1    1       0
2    0       1
3    1       0
4    0       1
5    0       1
6    1       0
```

We can bind it to a single dataset with `cbind`

```
out2 <- do.call(cbind, out_lst)
out2
#  bad good ok eggs sausage
#1   0    1  0    1       0
#2   1    0  0    0       1
#3   0    0  1    1       0
#4   0    0  1    0       1
#5   0    1  0    0       1
#6   1    0  0    1       0
```

---

Or use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(multiple[-1])))
```